Effective and Actual PPI issues with jpg vs. tiff photos in Indesign
I'm trying to make a print at 12"x12," and the .jpg photo I have has an Actual PPI of 300.
When I place the photo, I have to blow it up so that the Effective PPi ends up being quite low (between 77 and 230 PPI).
Is there something I can do to make the Effective PPI 300? I tried saving out the image as a much larger .tiff file but the PPI only increases a little bit.

No.
From reading things, I'd estimate you are enlarging the image by around 400%. That is too great an enlargement for any raster image - regardless of the format container, jpg, tiff, psd, etc..
The image you are using is too small for your desired use. You need to find a much larger (dimensioned) image at 300ppi. Or a much higher PPI image so that the effective resolution does not drop below 240ppi in Indesign.
(240ppi is really the minimum necessary for a 150lpi line screen - which is most common).
If you must use this particular image... it will look pretty horrible, but you can increase the size by 400% and resample in Photoshop. A 400% enlargement is going to create a great deal of pixel interpolation and ruin much of the detail in any image. You are better off just finding a more appropriately sized image for you needs.

Thank you for your response. I think I have a better idea of what the problem is now and now I can look for a better photo. Much appreciated!

or use AI image enhancement services. Online services or desktop solutions (e.g. Topaz Gigapixel)

Hello Eugene, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your contribution. We generally seek long answers here, that don't just provide a tool, but also explain why this tool would be a good solution to the question. Please [edit] your answer to provide more information on why you think this is a good solution.
